# CS-Cart custom module for product filter from home page

Tags: filter, product, cs-cart

I am new for the cs-cart,as per my client requirment i need to place the product filter from the home page (ref : https://www.powerbulbs.com/ - look the slider left hand).

My requirment is place the category dropdown and brand dropdown,once i submitted the form,product will be need to list based on the given input.

Is that possible in CS-Cart? if its possible means kindly give the some input for get the solution.

Comment: did you get the solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to do this directly from your admin dashboard, from the Blocks area. But it highly depends on how that function was implemented. It could be that's hardcoded in a template.